# Why is HttpApplication constructor called several times

Tags: asp.net, httpapplication

Can somebody explain why the constructor of a custom class derived from **HttpApplication** is called several times upon application startup?

My code structure is the following:
 - My **Global** class in global.asax derives from **CustomApp** class.
 - The **CustomApp** class derives from **HttpApplication** class

The **Global** class is created at startup, but when I place a breakpoint in the constructor, it is invoked several times!  I thought there should be only one instance of **Application** class created?

Am I wrong?

**UPD**: the web server can indeed create several **HttpApplication** instances to process multiple requests coming in at the same time. This becomes especially apparent when you place a breakpoint in the constructor of your **HttpApplication** descendant. Several requests will be pending from the client (http content, CSS files, etc) and to serve each of them the web server will create new instances of HttpApp. So, beware of this, when writing the application initialization logic.

Comment: is it possible to post a cut-down code snippet that exhibits this behaviour?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the ASP.NET runtime may create more than one HttpApplication per application domain. So HttpApplication.Init and the Ctor may get called more than once.

If you want to have initialization code that only runs once, you should use the Application_Start event which will only be called once per app.

Comment: Is there an event (or similar) which I can hook in to for Applcation_Start since I need to have my HttpApplication class outside of the website ?

Comment: Just implement a method `Applcation_Start` in Global.asax.cs and it will be automatically wired up and called at start time.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that events like `AuthenticateRequest` or `AcquireRequestState` don't fire if you register event handlers in `Application_Start()`. You may want to register them in `Init()` which is an override to `HttpApplication`.

Answer (score 9):

Please have a look at a post [global.asax in ASP.NET](http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/global-asax-in-asp-net/) - it explains why there are multiple instances of the HttpApplication. Basically there are two pools: special and normal. Normal pool contains instances of the HttpApplication which are used by the requests (each requests has its own HttpApplication instance). Special pool contains HttpApplication objects used for application-level events (like Application_Start, Application_Error).