# Hangfire configuration and Ninject configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, hangfire, hangfire.ninject

I have an MVC 5 application which uses Ninject and I am adding Hangfire to it.

When I have added Ninject, I have used the `NinjectWebCommon` nuget package because of its simplicity in the configuration. So for now Ninject is configured through the `NinjectWebCommon` class which create a standard kernel and add the bindings.

Moreover I have created some custom module that I load when creating the kernel

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel() {
    var kernel = new StandardKernel( new MyCustomModule() );
    try {
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod( ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel );
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices( kernel );
        return kernel;
    }
    catch {
        kernel.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

The Ninject Web Common is registered through the `WebActivatorEx` class

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod( typeof( MyProject.Web.NinjectWebCommon ), "Start" )]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute( typeof( MyProject.Web.NinjectWebCommon ), "Stop" )]
```

Now the problem is related on how to make Hangfire to see the Ninject configuration. By looking at the `Hangfire.Ninject` package I can read

> The package provides an extension method for IGlobalConfiguration
>   interface:
>
> `var kernel = new StandardKernel();`
>   `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(kernel);`

Now my question are:

- Because of the `IGlobalConfiguration` interface, I should add the Hangfire Ninject configuration inside the OWIN startup method (where the Hangfire config is already placed). How should I get the current Ninject Kernel (the one that NinjectWebCommon has configured?
- What about the order of execution? Is the `WebActivatorEx`executing before or after the OWIN startup?
- What happens if I try to execute the configuration twice?

More generally, how can I share the Ninject configuration between the two?

Answer (score 12):

> How should I get the current Ninject Kernel

Looking at the code of [`Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common/Bootstrapper.cs) shows that it stores a single static instance of the kernel, and exposes it via the `Kernel` property.  This means that you can do this inside the OWIN startup method:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(
                                     new Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper().Kernel);
```

and you'll have the same `IKernel` instance, complete with whatever bindings you configured in `NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices`

> What about the order of execution? Is the `WebActivatorEx` executing before or after the OWIN startup?

Before.  You can verify this (as I did) by setting breakpoints in each. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955866/when-does-preapplicationstartmethod-actually-get-triggered-to-run)

> More generally, how can I share the Ninject configuration between the two?
>
> What happens if I try to execute the configuration twice?

The kernel configuration is the "composition root." According to Mark Seemann, a preeminent expert on the subject, there [should only be one of these in the application](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/), and [it should be as close as possible to the application's entry point.](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)

Comment: Edit: Replaced custom property suggestion with better Bootstrapper based suggestion, and added a bit on composition roots.