# When does ApplicationShutdownMethod called?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I came across the nice explanation of :

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(xxx), "Start")]
```

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955866/when-does-preapplicationstartmethod-actually-get-triggered-to-run).

So I am more curious to know, when does the **ApplicationShutdownMethod** execute?
As the code implies(below), the **Shutdow()** is disposing the UnityContainer instanse.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(UnityWebActivator), "Shutdown")]
    public static void Shutdown()
    {
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
        container.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This code runs at the time **Dispose** is called on **the last HttpModule** in the app."
Answer copied from [here](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/new-features-in-webactivator-13.html).